# Design for large scale parameter validation for JPA?

Tags: java, json

I have a method that takes in a JSON and takes out the data and distributes it to various strings so that they can be set in an entity and persisted. My example below is quite simple but for my actual code I have about 20+ fields
For example see
    public Projects createProject(JsonObject jsonInst) {

```
Projects projectInst = new Projects();
String pId = jsonInst.get("proId").getAsString();
String pName = jsonInst.get("proName").getAsString();
String pStatus = jsonInst.get("proStatus").getAsString();
String pCustId = jsonInst.get("proCustId").getAsString();
String pStartDate = jsonInst.get("proStartDate").getAsString();
...

//Set the entity data
projectInst.setProjectId(pId);
projectInst.setProjectName(pName);
...
```

Notice if a varible dosent have a corrosponding entry in the Json this code will break with null pointer exception. Obviously I need to validate each parameter befopre calling .getAsString()

What is the best way to do this from a readability point of view I could create 2 varibles for each parameter and check and set for example.

```
if(jsonInst.get("proName")){
String pName = jsonInst.get("proName").getAsString();
}
```

Or should I wait for it to be set

```
if(!pName.isEmpty()){
projectInst.setName(pName)
}
...
```

Which of these do you think is the best parameter to use for preventing errors.
Is there a way to handle if something is set on a large scale so that I can reduce the amount of code I have to write before I use that varible?

Comment: What does it have to do with JPA?

Comment: Sorry, The projectInst is an entity with getters and setters. I need to make a quick edit

Comment: Might also be useful to indicate what JsonObject actually is i.e. give the FQ class name or the library name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a method that will take field name as parameter and will return json value for that field :

```
private String getJSONData(String field,JsonObject json){
    String data=null;
    if(json.has(field)){
        data=json.get(field).getAsString();
    }   
    return data;    
}
```

you can call this method for each of your field:

```
String pId = getJSONData("proId",jsonInst);
```

By this way you can not only escape `NullPointerException`, but also avoid code repetition.